# How do i tell IntelliJ that the missing module WILL be provided?

Tags: webpack, webstorm, intellij-14

[image]

IntelliJ is right to whine about this. Elm is not a file, it's a result of this config in webpack:

```
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.es6'],
    alias: {
      Elm: path.resolve('builds/intellij/scripts/elm-program.js')
    }
  }
```

How do I tell intellij that there's nothing to worry about? That it's gonna be provided eventually?

These are the only options provided by the suggestions menu:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the `>` button next to `Install 'Elm'` or hit Right, then choose to either disable the inspection or suppress it for current statement:

[image]

Webpack aliases are not currently supported, please vote for [WEB-13409](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13409) and linked tickets

Comment: Can i have this rule just for this specific module in this specific project?

Comment: you can either disable warning for current import in current file, or disable the inspection for all imports in the project. there is no way to suppress it for particular import in all files at once